# simple if, else if .cannot get it to work

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

im trying to make a small program that asks for a number between 1-10 and then gives out a different prewritten response. this is what i have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AlasFutureTeller
{
        public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        System.out.println("I CAN READ YOUR FUTURE!");
        System.out.println("TYPE A NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10 TO MEET YOUR FATE!!");
        Scanner oneTen = new Scanner (System.in);
        int one == oneTen;
        if (oneTen=="one")
            System.out.println("YOU WILL GO TO SLEEP TODAY!!");
        else if ( oneTen=="two")
            System.out.println("YOU WILL HAVE A BIRTHDAY EVERY YEAR UNTIL YOU DIE!!");
        else if ( oneTen=="three")
            System.out.println("YOU WILL SHOWER SOMETIME IN THIS YEAR!!");
        else if ( oneTen=="four")
            System.out.println("YOU WILL LIVE UNTIL YOU THE DAY YOU DIE!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and your question is...?

Comment: it doesnt work at all, how would i go about doing this.

Comment: *How* does it not work? Please be way more specific.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:  That's weird.  Our dupe-hammers aren't working.  Perhaps Java wasn't in the original tag. :<

Comment: You also want to change `int one == oneTen;` to `String one = oneTen.nextLine();` for your code to compile/work.

Comment: While technically a duplicate of the linked question, I question why you tell your users to type in a number between "1 and 10", then check for "one", "two", "three", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `Strings` to `ints` silly goose!

```
if (oneTen=="one")
```

Try:

```
if (oneTen.nextInt() == 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("I CAN READ YOUR FUTURE!");
        System.out.println("TYPE A NUMBER BETWEEN 1 AND 10 TO MEET YOUR FATE!!");

        Integer number = new Scanner (System.in).nextInt();

        if (number.equals(1))
            System.out.println("YOU WILL GO TO SLEEP TODAY!!");
        else if (number.equals(2))
            System.out.println("YOU WILL HAVE A BIRTHDAY EVERY YEAR UNTIL YOU DIE!!");
        else if (number.equals(3))
            System.out.println("YOU WILL SHOWER SOMETIME IN THIS YEAR!!");
        else if ( number.equals(4))
            System.out.println("YOU WILL LIVE UNTIL YOU THE DAY YOU DIE!!");

    }

}
```

You can change the type of variable number to 'int' and change the compare mode to

if(number == 1)...

You can choose what do you like more. But for now you need understand that int is a primitive type and Integer is a wrapper of this primitive type that give to you an object that represent the primitive type.

Comment: Why would he need to extend past primitive types for this simple problem?

Comment: ​Java is OO Language... Why should i use primitive variables?

Ok... have cases that i need use it but at almost all cases i don't need it.​


An person that is beginning at language could be confused the symbols '=' and '=='.

If i use primitive variable i need compare with '==' when i use 'Wrapper' i could use .equals and it is very better to understand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any and every CS course (that deals with Java) forbids students to stray away from primitive types, kind of contradicts what you're saying.

Comment: Do you prefer work with primitive types or wrapper types?

Comment: Depends on what I'm doing.